# Change path to Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, path, directory

I started a test project which I was saving to my Dropbox folder, that project grew into the real deal.  I need to move that project to my local Git repo, however Xcode is not letting me do so.  I've copied the content to the new folder, but if I open the project from the new folder and make any changes, they are saved to the original.  I've Googled and tried everything I've found, but no matter what, my code always gets saved to the Dropbox original.

If I delete the Dropbox folder, when I open Xcode and make any changes, Xcode will crash.  Put it back and Xcode will behave itself, but all new changes are saved to the Dropbox folder.

Any ideas or links to anything I might have missed?

Cheers.

Comment: Ignore me, I was being dumb.  Simply had to close the project then re-open it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer was to close the project in Xcode then re-open the new/moved project file.